# Flexicontent 1.5.3 installation on joomla leads to com_content access problem

Tags: joomla1.5

After the installation of Flexicontent 1.5.3 on Joomla 1.5 has lead to com_content access problems. ie other user roles have no access to the com_content but only to the Flexicontent .
Access to both com_content and Flexicontent is only thru administrator permissions.

Can someone please give a solution to this problem.

Thanks,
Ravindra Hari

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both. See description of component http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/10667

> **FLEXIcontent** is primarily an advanced content management system developed to **replace the native article manager of Joomla! 1.5 (com_content)**

You have to modify all you links that point to com_content to flexicont component.